Textbox size is changed after refresh / zoom / rotate / copy
I am using fabric js in my angular application. The issue I am facing is that when I create a Textbox fabric object and either zoom or rotate the canvas, copy the textbox or refresh the page, the textbox height is changed - the text is adjusted to the lines. Here is the code:
object = new fabric.Textbox(this.translate.instant('COMMENTS.CREATE_LABEL'), {
          width: 100,
          left: this.#x,
          top: this.#y,
          fontSize: this.toolboxService.selectedFontSize,
          stroke: this.toolboxService.objectColor,
          fill: this.toolboxService.objectColor,
          textAlign: 'center',
          fontFamily: 'Arial',
          backgroundColor: this.toolboxService.backgroundColor,
          padding: 0,
        });
      }

      if (object) {
        this.drawService.canvas.add(object);
        this.drawService.canvas.setActiveObject(object);
        this.#started = true;
        this.drawService.canvas.renderAll();
      }

This is the before and after of the textbox object:

